# Read a list of subdirectories from command line arguement

Tags: python, directory

I would like to pass in multiple command line arguments to create a list of subdirectories to read. Currently I pass them in from the command line as:

`python foo.py -s 'P1,P2' -c 'X,Y'`

I would like this to read only the subdirectories:

```
P1/X/
P1/Y/
P2/X/
P2/Y/
```

I've tried the below, but it ends up reading every subdirectory:

```
path = os.path.join('*['+s+']', '*['+c+']', '*.txt') 
    files = glob.glob(path)
```

How can I limit this to only those subdirectories from the combination of lists?

Comment: Seems working to me.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want, in terms of generating the list

```
>>> import os
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [os.path.join(s, c, '*.txt') for s, c in product(['P1', 'P2'], ['X', 'Y'])]
['P1/X/*.txt', 'P1/Y/*.txt', 'P2/X/*.txt', 'P2/Y/*.txt']
```

Obviously, you'll need to turn your two arguments into two lists to feed to the `product` function.